# Do you need EMV (chip & pin/sign) card in Indonesia?

Tags: payment-cards, indonesia

Do you need to use an EMV (chip & pin, or chip & sign) card in Indonesia? Or do they still accept magnetic swipe cards there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of september last year, I was able to withdraw cash with  both VISA and MasterCard from ATMs in indonesia, both were swipe cards. I didn't pay directly at point of sale using any of my cards since that incurs a fee for both of my cards.

However I expect swipe cards to be supported anywhere for the foreseeable future since even in my home country (germany), I have not yet seen any place where EMV is supported, but swipe is not.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the chip.

I have an Indonesian card and it is a simple swipe card. However, do not rely too much on this option. Communication networks often fail and ATM are often empty. Try to always keep some cash available.